# phpmyadmin gives syntax error to join 2 tables if a column contains substring

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin, syntax-error, inner-join

"mytest_people" and "mytest_hobbies":

```
  PK                 FK    <---  PK
+----+------+------+------+    +----+-----------------+
| Id | Name | Age  | H_ID |    | Id | Hobby           |
+----+------+------+------+    +----+-----------------+
| 0  | Pete | 100  | 0    |    | 0  | Reading News    |
| 1  | Mark | 5    | 1    |    | 1  | Reading Fiction |
| 2  | Bob  | 33   | 3    |    | 2  | Writing         |
| 3  | Lulu | 12   | 1    |    | 3  | Cooking         |
+----+------+------+------+    +----+-----------------+
```

This is what I am expecting to get:

```
+----+------+------+-----------------+
| Id | Name | Age  | Hobby           |
+----+------+------+-----------------+
| 0  | Pete | 100  | Reading News    |
| 1  | Mark | 5    | Reading Fiction |
| 3  | Lulu | 12   | Reading Fiction |
+----+------+------+-----------------+
```

This is in everyday-ish words /pseudo code:

```
IN DATABASE "my_new_test_data_base"
SELECT COLUMNS "Id, Name, Age"
FROM TABLE "mytest_people"
WHERE COLUMN "H_ID"
    EQUALS COLUMN "Id"
    FROM TABLE "mytest_hobbies"
THEN JOIN COLUMN Hobby
FROM TABLE mytest_hobbies
ON CONDITION Hobby VALUES
    CONTAIN 'Reading%' SUBSTRING;
```

This is my latest attempt at the SQL code:

```
USE my_new_test_data_base
SELECT mytest_people.Id, mytest_people.Name, mytest_people.Age FROM mytest_people
INNER JOIN mytest_hobbies (`Hobby`)
ON mytest_people.H_ID = mytest_hobbies.Id
WHERE `Hobby` LIKE 'Reading%';
```

This is the error I get:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT mytest_people.Id, mytest_people.Name, mytest_people.Age
> FROM mytest_peop' at line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some small misstale, every comand has to be ended by semicolion

and aliases don't belong in brackets

```
USE my_new_test_data_base;
SELECT mytest_people.Id, mytest_people.Name, mytest_people.Age ,mytest_hobbies.`Hobby`
FROM mytest_people
INNER JOIN mytest_hobbies 
ON mytest_people.H_ID = mytest_hobbies.Id
WHERE mytest_hobbies.`Hobby` LIKE 'Reading%';
```

Comment: For this it throws error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT mytest_people.Id, mytest_people.Name, mytest_people.Age, mytest_hobbies.' at line 2`. i use Xampp v3.2.3. compiled Mar.7.2019.. and whatever version MariaDB came with it. I am new to this so I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: this has no problem what so ever see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=403cde3228690969df41eb4c02afcb80 so you added a typo

Answer (score 1):

If less typing is your thing:

```
SELECT p.Id
     , p.Name
     , p.Age 
     , h.hobby
  FROM my_new_test_data_base.mytest_people p
  JOIN my_new_test_data_base.mytest_hobbies h
    ON p.H_ID = h.Id
 WHERE h.Hobby LIKE 'Reading%';
```